# Bing Maps and OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, maps

I'm researching the contribution of Bing Maps' aerial imagery for contribution to OpenStreetMap for tracing imagery. I understand that Bing allowed OpenStreetMap [only the right to trace the imagery](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bing_Maps). But if a certain Bing image (e.g. downtown Los Angeles on January 31, 2017) was obtained from DigitalGlobe WorldView 3, does this imply that DigitalGlobe also allowed the tracing to OpenStreetMap as well? Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_Maps#Global_Ortho_Program

Comment: There is also 2. of Bing Maps Terms about Bing Maps and OpenStreetMap https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/product/imagery-service-editor-app-apis-terms

Comment: OSM has  Digital Globe info here https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DigitalGlobe#Legal_permissions